# When creating many select lists with .map(), how can I pass the unique value of each one to the parent component to combined together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

new to react native and redux and not sure how I should go about solving this problem. 
Basically I'm trying to create a meal delivery app like Uber eats. Now when a user selects a specific meal they may need to choose multiple add ons for the meal using a select list. I used .map() to create a select list for each add on (e.g. we may have a side and a drinks select list. Side: [fries, salad], Drinks: [coke, pepsi])

Where I'm having trouble is passing the current value of each select list to the parent component so the users selection can be combined with other data and then added to their cart. What would the best way for me to go about handling this? I'm really struggling and any help will be much appreciated!

Here is the current set up of my app:

Meal component (parent)

```
const Meal = props => {
const meal = props.navigation.getParam("meal");

const cartItems = useSelector(state => state.cartItems);

const addOns = () => {
if (!meal.addOns) {
  return;
} else {
  return meal.addOns.map((addOn, index) => {
    const isRequired = () => {
      if (addOn.isRequired) {
        return (
          <CustomTextBold
            text={`${addOn.type} (required)`}
            style={{ paddingVertical: 5 }}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <CustomTextBold
            text={addOn.type}
            style={{ paddingVertical: 5 }}
          />
        );
      }
    };

    return (
      <View key={index} style={styles.pickerContainer}>
        {isRequired()}
        <AddOnPicker items={addOn.options} type={addOn.type} />
      </View>
    );
  });
 }
};

const price = meal.price * quantity;

return (
<ScrollView>
          {addOns()}
</ScrollView>
);
};

export default Meal;
```

Select List component (child)

```
const AddOnPicker = props => {
const addOnItems = [];

const pushItems = () => {
props.items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.cost === 0) {
    addOnItems.push({
      label: item.option,
      value: item.option,
      name: item.option,
      price: item.cost
    });
  } else {
    addOnItems.push({
      label: item.option + " " + ` (+N$${item.cost})`,
      value: item.option + " " + ` (+N$${item.cost})`,
      name: item.option,
      price: item.cost
    });
  }
 });
};

pushItems();

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handlePickerValue = value => {
const item = addOnItems.find(item => item.label === value);
dispatch(setItems(item));
};

return (
<RNPickerSelect
  placeholder={placeholder}
  style={pickerSelectStyles} // value={pickerValue}
  onValueChange={value => {
    handlePickerValue(value);
  }}
  items={addOnItems}
 />
 );
};

export default AddOnPicker;
```